# Rails - Editing User and Profile Models from separate Settings Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm struggling to figure out exactly how to get this to work, but essentially I have 2 models:

```
 class User
 class Profile
```

One User has One Profile.

I also have a SettingsController with "profile" and "update" actions:

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController

  def profile
    @profile = User.find_by_id(current_user).profile
  end

  def update
    set_profile
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:name)
    end

end
```

And the /settings/profile page:

```
<h1>Settings</h1>
<div>

  <div>
    Name: <%= @profile.name %>
  </div>
  <%= form_with(model: @profile, local: true) do |form| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :username %> 
      <%= form.text_field :username %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :surname %> 
      <%= form.text_field :surname %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= form.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

My routes:

```
get 'settings/profile', to: 'settings#profile', as: :settings_profile
post 'settings/profile', to: 'settings#update', as: :update_settings_profile
```

How can I get my form (from SettingsController) to allow fields for my User and Profile models?

*Edit

I have overridden my profile_path to pull from the username:

```
def profile_path(profile)
  '/' + 'profiles' + '/' + profile.user.username
end
```

Currently, when I load the page containing the form, I get this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Have edited original question - How can I get my form (from SettingsController) to allow fields for my User and Profile models?

Comment: Your code looks ok. What happens when you submit the form?

Comment: @Pavan have added some extra code to my original question. Currently, I can't even load the page itself without getting past this issue. I have found that I can fix the error by changing my form from "form_with(model: @profile)" to "form_with(url: settings_profile_path)" but from here the form does not save any data.

Comment: I can't understand why you defined `profile_path(profile)` method. Anyways have you tried `<%= form_with(model: @profile, local: true, url: update_settings_profile_path) do |form| %>`? It should work. And if you want to save the `username` and `surname`, then you need to whitelist those in the `profile_params` like `params.require(:profile).permit(:username,:surname)`

Comment: Great point - I've overwritten the profile_path method, so that a profile is found by looking for the User.username - so /profiles/username - for both clarity and simplicity in terms of the usability of the site. You're spot-on about form_with - works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the form as `<%= form_with(model: @profile, local: true) do |form| %>`, it is equivalent to `<form action="/profiles/1" method="post" data-remote="false">`. You need to tell Rails to map the form to the *custom url* like so

```
<%= form_with(model: @profile, url: update_settings_profile_path, local: true)
```

And you need to *whitelist* `username` and `surname` in the `profile_params` in order to reflect the changes in the DB.

```
def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:username, surname)
end
```

Comment: This worked immediately - didn't realise it was possible to set both the model and the url with form_with, so really appreciate your help!

Comment: can I ask, the form currently does not accept any fields for my User model - what would be the best way to extend my form and controller to allow for fields from both/either model?