# Rails - Editing multiple Models from separate Controller and Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

This is an extension of this original question: [Rails - Editing User and Profile Models from separate Settings Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472570/rails-editing-user-and-profile-models-from-separate-settings-controller)

My form works perfectly for editing a single model (Profile), however I have attempted to extend this to also allow for a user to edit some of the fields from the User model. Currently, the entire form is no longer saving any data - but I am not seeing any visible error messages in browser, other than the "success" message in my update method is not firing.

How can I successfully extend this setup to allow for both User and Profile fields to be saved in the same form? The form currently edits a Profile, and then allows fields_for a user - is this the wrong way around?

I have 2 models, User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy

  before_create :create_profile

  private
  def create_profile
    build_profile(name: username)
  end

end
```

and Profile:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

end
```

Both models are editable via the SettingsController:

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController

  def profile
    @profile = User.find_by_id(current_user).profile
  end

  def update
    set_profile
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: settings_path, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:name, user_attributes: [:email])
    end
end
```

On settings/profile, a user's profile is editable with the following form:

```
<h1>Settings</h1>
<div>

  <div>
    Name: <%= @profile.name %>
  </div>

  <%= form_with(model: @profile, url: update_settings_profile_path, local: true) do |form| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :name %> 
      <%= form.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <%= form.fields_for :user do |user_form| %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= user_form.label :email %> 
        <%= user_form.text_field :email %>
      </div>

    <% end %>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= form.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Are here are the list of routes that show the profile page, and the update method for all of the other methods:

```
get 'settings', to: redirect('settings/profile')
get 'settings/profile', to: 'settings#profile', as: :settings_profile
patch 'settings', to: 'settings#update', as: :update_settings
```

Parameters when the form is submitted: (Removed auth token for clarity.)

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"X", "profile"=>{"name"=>"John Doe", "user_attributes"=>{"email"=>"test@email.com", "id"=>"22"}}, "commit"=>"Update Profile"}
```

Schema: (Basic columns removed for clarity.)

```
create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.bigint "user_id"
  ...
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_profiles_on_user_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "email", default: "", null: false
  t.string "username", default: "", null: false
  ...
end
```

Appreciate any tips!

Comment: I am not sure why you are accepting nested fields under profile, it should be reversed. User `has_one` Profile, so its better to make user form and accept nested profile there.

Comment: Can you show schema of user and profile from schema.rb?

Comment: Can you update the question with the params that appear when you submit the form?

Comment: @Gabbar have added basic schema to the original question.

Comment: @Pavan have also added the parameters when the form is submitted - it looks correct, so I'm not exactly sure what the issue is. Could it be that there is a user_id but no profile_id?

Comment: @Kobius Did my answer worked? If not try adding `:id` to the `user_attributes` in the `profile_params` like so `params.require(:profile).permit(:name, user_attributes: [:id, :email])`

Comment: From `accepts_nested_attributes_for` [:update_only](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) option docs: For a one-to-one association, the nested attributes are used to update the existing record only if they include the record's `:id` value. Otherwise a new record will be instantiated and used to replace the existing one.